# Why is [a..b] an empty list when a > b?

Tags: haskell

If I enter `[5..1]` into the Haskell console it returns `[]`, whereas I expected `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

In general, `[a..b] = []` if `a > b`. Why?

Comment: Somewhat related: [math.SE/How should one interpret an interval like \[2,1\]
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57460/how-should-one-interpret-an-interval-like-2-1)

Comment: I wouldn't like that semantics. This is because it is very convenient to have `length [1..n] == n` for every non negative `n`. This would be broken if `[1..0]` is `[1,0]`. Usually the programmer wants a known-increasing or known-decreasing sequence, not a sequence which flips direction as soon as the extremes flip. (We could however have a library function for the "flipping" variant -- is there any common need for that, though?)

Comment: Note that the programming language `R` has a colon operator that counts up or down, so `1:3` is `c(1,2,3)` while `3:1` is `c(3,2,1)`.  This is occasionally "convenient" for interactive use, and a nightmare for writing reliable programs; I've been bitten by this behavior (specifically, where the special case `1:0 == empty vector` would have been correct but the actual result `c(1,0)` caused a bug) dozens of times.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Report covers the details. In [Section 3.10](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10):

> Arithmetic sequences satisfy these identities:
>
> ```
> [ e1..e3 ]    =   enumFromTo e1 e3
> ```

In [Section 6.3.4](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4):

> For the types `Int` and `Integer`, the enumeration functions have the following meaning:
>
> - The sequence `enumFromTo e1 e3` is the list `[e1,e1 + 1,e1 + 2,…e3]`. The list is empty if `e1  >  e3`.
>
> For `Float` and `Double`, the semantics of the `enumFrom` family is given by the rules for `Int` above, except that the list terminates when the elements become greater than `e3 + i∕2` for positive increment `i`, or when they become less than `e3 + i∕2` for negative `i`.

Then the next question is, "Why was the Report specified that way?". There I think the answer is that this choice is quite natural for a mathematician, which most of the original committee were to some extent. It also has a number of nice properties:

- If `[x..y]` has *n* values, then `[x..y-1]` and `[x+1..y]` have *n-1* values (where in *n-1*, the subtraction saturates at 0, an *ahem* natural choice).
- Checking whether a particular element is in the range `[x..y]` only requires checking that it is bigger than `x` and smaller than `y` -- you need not first determine which of `x` or `y` is bigger.
- It prevents a certain class of surprising off-by-one errors: if you want to take the next *n>=0* elements after `x`, you can write `[x..x+n-1]`. If you choose the other rule, where `[x..y]` might mean `[y,y+1,...,x]` if `y` is smaller, there is no way to create an empty list with `[_.._]` syntax, so no uniform way to take the next *n* elements. One would have to write the more cumbersome `if n>0 then [x..x+n-1] else []`; and it would be very easy to forget to write this check.

If you would like the list `[5,4,3,2,1]`, that may be achieved by specifying an explicit second step, as in `[5,4..1]`.